# Showing that a polyhedron doesn't contain an integral point

Tags: optimization, polyhedra, integer-programming, polytopes

I have the following question: I have to decide if a polytope $P = \{x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{\ell}\mid Ax=0\}$ contains an integral point except $x=0$, for hundreds or thousands of different matrices $A$ (some also huge). So my approach was to solve the optimization problem

\begin{align*}
\rm{max}\quad &0\\
 \rm{s.t.}\quad &x \in P \cap \mathbb{Z}^\ell\\
& x\neq 0
\end{align*}
and check this for infeasiblity. For this I use a solver like CPLEX or similar. Now my question: How reliable is the result? If CPLEX answers "infeasible", can I be absolutely sure that there is no integral point in $P$?

Additionally, is there a better approach for this?

I haven't found anything on the reliability, so I would be very happy if someone could answer this or give a source where I can read something on that!

Comment: I found this paper, ["An Algorithmic Theory of Lattice Points
in Polyhedra"](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/barvpomm.pdf) which discusses the problem at length.  It only seems to consider the case where $A$ is an integer matrix though, so I don't know if it's applicable to your problem or not.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for the reference! However, I don't really see how this helps in my case, even though my matrices are integral (consisting of 0, -1 and 1, in fact). Moreover, I cannot assure that my polyhedra are actually polytopes...

Comment: Too bad.  I don't know anything about the paper; just found it and hoped it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate $x \neq 0$ as $\sum_i x_i \geq 1$.

The algorithms used by CPLEX to determine feasibility (branch&bound and cutting planes, combined with the simplex or barrier method) are guaranteed to give the correct answer. Any book on combinatorial optimization proves that. However, the implementation of those algorithms in CPLEX is limited by numerical precision, so neither a *feasible* or *infeasible* result is reliable.

A feasible result is easy to check yourself. For an infeasible instance, you could enable just the cutting plane algorithm and request the cutting planes and certificate of infeasibility from CPLEX to validate the answer with arbitrary precision arithmetic. I suspect that you will find that the certificate is invalid, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how I can enable "request the cutting planes and certificate of infeasibility from CPLEX"? Can't really find anything on that...

Comment: @python15 https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7a5b837a-5293-47a6-8629-4596a494e916

Comment: https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2010/07/infeasible-lps-and-farkas-certificates.html (written by prubin!)

Comment: Well, the blog post from @prubin is really great, but only describes the case of LPs, but not IPs. Do you know a "translation" of Farkas certificates to IPs?

Comment: @python15 if you only use cutting planes, the final LP solves the IP

Answer (score 1):

The reliability of a declaration of infeasibility will depend on numeric properties of A and its submatrices. CPLEX has a parameter that you can use to tell it to pay extra attention to numerical issues (at the cost of slowing it down). Even that is not a guarantee, though. With floating point arithmetic, there are no absolute certainties.

You might also pay attention to the constraint tolerance. CPLEX will accept $x$ as satisfying $a'x=0$ if $|a'x|\le \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is a parameter you can tweak. Similarly, it accepts $x_j$ as integer-valued if $x_j$ is within $\delta > 0$ of the nearest integer, where $\delta$ is another parameter you can tweak. Generally speaking, the larger you make $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, the more credible a claim of infeasibility is, but that too comes at a cost: if you increase the parameters and CPLEX says it has a feasible solution, you will need to check the solution and, if not really feasible, solve the model again with tighter parameter values.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! However, if I need to know whether the problem is infeasible, then the approach "solve and if the solution is not feasible, then tighten the parameter values" doesn't really help, right? It wouldn't be a problem for me if I sometimes get "false feasibles" (problems where I obtain a solution which is actually not), but I definitely want to prevent that the algorithm says "infeasible", but it is feasible in fact... seems a bit hopeless, though...

Comment: If you can tolerate false feasibles but not false infeasibles, that's an argument for relaxing the integrality and constraint tolerances (a little). If the solver reports the problem is infeasible, you have a bit more confidence that the result is correct (and not a numeric problem). If the solver reports the problem is feasible, more lax tolerances make that result more suspect, but you're saying you can tolerate an occasional error in that direction.

Comment: This is quite clear to me, yes. But this way I only obtain "a bit more confidence" and no full confidence, as it is needed in my case...